# Autocomplete TextInput with ListView - Have to tap ListView twice to select List Item

Tags: javascript, listview, reactjs, react-native

I have a textInput with a ListView below it and it acts like an Autocomplete. I am using no third party libraries, just react native components. However since when entering text into the TextInput, the TextInput has focus, and the ListView does not, you have the tap the listView once just to give it focus, then tap it a second time to select a list item. Is there are a way to make it so that you can tap a ListView item once, and it registers as a tap on the ListItem, rather than having to tap twice?

Code:

```
const getDisplay = (shouldHideResults) => {
  return shouldHideResults ? 'none' : 'flex'
}

var ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 })

let Location = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles1.container}>
      <TextInput
        style={styles1.textinput}
        onChangeText={text => changeText(props, text)}
        placeholder="Location"
        value={props.locationInput}
        ref={input => locationInputElement = input} />
      <ListView
        dataSource={ds.cloneWithRows(props.autocompleteResults.predictions)}
        renderRow={place => renderAutocompleteItem(props, place)}
        style={{ 
          display: getDisplay(shouldHideResults)
        }} />
    </View>
  )
}

var styles1 = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
  },
  textinput: {
    marginTop: 30,
    backgroundColor: '#DDDDDD',
    height: 40,
    width: 200
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` property of your `ListView` to `true`.

```
<ListView
    dataSource={ds.cloneWithRows(props.autocompleteResults.predictions)}
    renderRow={place => renderAutocompleteItem(props, place)}
    style={{ 
      display: getDisplay(shouldHideResults)
    }} 
    keyboardShouldPersistTaps={true}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

What i did was wrapping the view with TouchableWithoutFeedback and upon pressing anywhere in the view  i dismiss the keyboard, please go through the below code snippet:

```
import { Keyboard, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native';

render()
{
  return(
   <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => Keyboard.dismiss() } >
      <View style={styles1.container}>
      <TextInput
        style={styles1.textinput}
        onChangeText={text => changeText(props, text)}
        placeholder="Location"
        value={props.locationInput}
        ref={input => locationInputElement = input} />
      <ListView
        dataSource={ds.cloneWithRows(props.autocompleteResults.predictions)}
        renderRow={place => renderAutocompleteItem(props, place)}
        style={{ 
          display: getDisplay(shouldHideResults)
        }} />
    </View>
   </TouchableWithoutFeedback >
)
}
```

Cheers :)

Comment: Doesn't work but thanks for trying. The list item is still not clickable initially as it is still out of focus when typing into the input.

Comment: give prop to the view that is keyboardShouldPersistTabs={true}